# gradlew.bat invalid directory in android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

How do I address the following error?

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;
```

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

I've been researching this for hours today but I haven't been able to find a solution that works for me. 
My JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67;

I tried setting it to JAVA_HOME C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.67; per the advise of a different thread but gradle is still throwing the same error in android studio.

Does anyone have an idea about what might be going wrong right now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `bin` from the end of your `JAVA_HOME` variable. If Android Studio still gives the same error, close and restart it. If you still get the same error, restart your machine.

Comment: I'm getting the same error for the change after restarting astudio, ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67; 
Also I tried Progra~1 but then I got this ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_67;

Comment: @feilong Are you sure that's the directory where your JDK is installed?

Comment: Yes sir, I checked it by putting the path into my cmd line and its right in there. Progra~2 was wrong however I only have the JRE in there. I'm restarting my machine to see if that helps any.

Comment: You need the JDK, not just the JRE.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I said Progra~2 was wrong because I only had the JRE in there that is the 32 bit install. But I currently have my environment set up running the 64-bit Java JDK in my Progra~1 folder. I just don't understand what gradle means about invalid directory.

Comment: @feilong It means that gradle can't find the JDK in the directory where `JAVA_HOME` is set.